Proximity operator
Let $\sigma_C(y)=\sup_{ z \in C} \langle z | y \rangle $. I want to find the proximity operator for the function $q=||.||^2+2\sigma_C$.
My attempt:
To find $$Prox_q(x)=\inf_{ y \in H}(||y||^2+2\sigma_C(y) + \frac{1}{2}||x-y||^2) $$
$$Prox_q(x)=\sup_{z\in C}\inf_{ y \in H}(||y||^2+2\langle y|z\rangle + \frac{1}{2}||x-y||^2)$$
I do not know how to proceed from here, Can someone give some hint?

$\sigma_C$ is the conjugate of the indicator function of $C$, so you can use the Moreau identity to compute the proximal operator of $\sigma_C$. Then you can express the proximal operator of $q$ in terms of the proximal operator of $\sigma_C$ by completing the square.

Using the first comment, I can compute the proximal operator of $\sigma_C$ as $x-P_C(x)$. But, am having trouble with expressing the proximal operator of $q$ as a square. Since, $\sigma_C$  is supremum over values in C.
$\text{prox}q(x) = \text{argmin}{y \in \mathcal{H}} \left( q(y) + \frac{1}{2} |y - x|^2 \right)$

We can complete the square then use the Moreau identity.
By definition
\begin{equation}
\text{prox}_q(x) = \arg \min_y \, 2 \sigma_C(y) + \| y \|^2 + \frac12 \| y - x \|^2.
\end{equation}
Note that
\begin{align*}
\| y \|^2 +  \frac12 \| y - x \|^2 &= \frac32( \| y \|^2 - \langle y, 2 x /3 \rangle + \frac49 \| x \|^2) - \frac16 \| x \|^2 \\
&= \frac32 \| y - \frac23 x \|^2 - \frac16 \| x \|^2.
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\text{prox}_q(x) &= \arg \min_y \frac23 \sigma_C(y) + \frac12 \| y - \frac23 x \|^2 \\
&= \text{prox}_{\frac23 \sigma_C}(\frac23 x)
\end{align*}
which can be evaluated using the Moreau identity.

Why did you divide by 3 in the last expression for the proximal operator?

When taking the arg min of a function, we can scale that function by any positive number that we want without changing the result. In this case scaling by 1/3 was convenient because it helped us recognize that after completing the square we are computing the proximal operator of the function $(2/3) \sigma_C$.
